# GP/GPU : ping pong technique with JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, gpgpu, jogl

I've tried to implement an reaction-diffusion model on GPU with JOGL and GLSL.

I use a ping pong technique with 2 FramebufferObject ( I've tried too with one FBO and 2 Colors attachements without success).
Shader seems correct since I've tried it in unity (with some adaptations) and it works.
After one week of trying many things, i'm completely out of idea to make this code works. I'm really not specialist of JOGL, so maybe i miss something evident.

The result is an image which becomes white with time : no reaction-diffusion behaviors and I don't understand why !

Thanks in advance for helps. Here is my code :

```
package gpu2;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.io.File;

import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLFBODrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.FBObject;
import com.jogamp.opengl.FBObject.Colorbuffer;
import com.jogamp.opengl.FBObject.ColorAttachment;
import com.jogamp.opengl.FBObject.TextureAttachment;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.glsl.ShaderCode;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.glsl.ShaderProgram;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.glsl.ShaderUtil;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.GLBuffers; 
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture; 
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO; 

import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLOffscreenAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.AWTGLReadBufferUtil;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableFactory;

import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.*;  // GL constants
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL2.*; // GL2 constants

import gpu2.ModelParam;

/**
 * JOGL 2.0 Program Template (GLCanvas)
 * This is a "Component" which can be added into a top-level "Container".
 * It also handles the OpenGL events to render graphics.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JOGL2Setup_GLCanvas extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener {
   // Define constants for the top-level container
   private static String TITLE = "JOGL 2.0 Setup (GLCanvas)";  // window's title
   private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 512;  // width of the drawable
   private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 512; // height of the drawable
   private static final int FPS = 30; // animator's target frames per second

   private final float[] canvasVertices = {
           -1f, -1f, 0.0f,
           -1f, 1f, 0.0f,
           1f, -1f, 0.0f,
           1f,  1f, 0.0f, 
   };

   private final float[] canvasTexCoords = {
           0.0f, 0.0f,
           0.0f, 1.0f,
           1.0f, 0.0f,
           1.0f, 1.0f,
};

   /** The entry main() method to setup the top-level container and animator */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Run the GUI codes in the event-dispatching thread for thread safety
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            // Create the OpenGL rendering canvas
            GLCanvas canvas = new JOGL2Setup_GLCanvas();
            canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));

            // Create a animator that drives canvas' display() at the specified FPS.
            final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, FPS, true);

            // Create the top-level container
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // Swing's JFrame or AWT's Frame
            frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                  // Use a dedicate thread to run the stop() to ensure that the
                  // animator stops before program exits.
                  new Thread() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                        if (animator.isStarted()) animator.stop();
                        System.exit(0);
                     }
                  }.start();
               }
            });
            frame.setTitle(TITLE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            animator.start(); // start the animation loop
         }
      });
   }

   // Setup OpenGL Graphics Renderer

   private GLU glu;  // for the GL Utility
   private GL2 gl;

   //OpenGl data
   private int vboVertices;
   private int vboTextCoord;
   private Texture textureFile;

   private FBObject fbo[];

   private ShaderProgram shaderCompute;
   private ShaderProgram shaderVisu;
   private ShaderProgram shaderComputeInit;

   private int currentSourceBuffer = 0;
   private int currentDestBuffer = 1;

   private int currentFrame = 0;
   private int maxFrameCount = 5000000;
   private float clearUniform = 0;

   ModelParam params = new ModelParam();

   public JOGL2Setup_GLCanvas() {
      this.addGLEventListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
      gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();      // get the OpenGL graphics context
      glu = new GLU();                         // get GL Utilities
      gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // set background (clear) color

      gl.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

      gl.glEnable( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL );
      gl.glEnable( GL_FRAMEBUFFER );
      gl.glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NEAREST); // best perspective correction

      viewOrtho(gl);

      gl.glViewport(0,0,CANVAS_WIDTH,CANVAS_HEIGHT);

      int[] buffers = new int[2];
      gl.glGenBuffers(2, buffers, 0);

      vboVertices = buffers[0];
      vboTextCoord = buffers[1];

      gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertices);
      gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, canvasVertices.length*(Float.SIZE/Byte.SIZE)*3, FloatBuffer.wrap(canvasVertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

      gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTextCoord);
      gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, canvasTexCoords.length*(Float.SIZE/Byte.SIZE)*2, FloatBuffer.wrap(canvasTexCoords), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

      gl.glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

      // ------------ create Texture Source------------------------
      textureFile = initializeTexture(); 
      if (textureFile==null) {
        System.out.println("cannot load texture from disk");  
      }

      // ------------ load shaders ------------------------
      shaderCompute = loadShader(gl, "compute.vsh", "compute.fsh");
      shaderComputeInit = loadShader(gl, "compute.vsh", "computeInit.fsh");
      shaderVisu    = loadShader(gl, "visu.vsh", "visu.fsh");

      // ------------ create FBO ------------------------

        initFBO();


   }

   /**
    * Called back by the animator to perform rendering.
    */
   @Override
   public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

       if (currentFrame < maxFrameCount) {
           prepareNextStep();

           renderToFBO();
           currentFrame++;

       }
       renderFBOToScreen();  
   }

     private void prepareNextStep() {
           currentSourceBuffer = 1 - currentSourceBuffer;
           currentDestBuffer = 1 - currentDestBuffer;
      }

   private void renderToFBO()
    {
        fbo[currentDestBuffer].bind(gl);
        //gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        viewOrtho(gl);

        shaderCompute.useProgram(gl, true);

        setShaderUniformFloat(gl, shaderCompute.program(), "diffuseU", 0.211f);
        setShaderUniformFloat(gl, shaderCompute.program(), "diffuseV", 0.088f);
        setShaderUniformFloat(gl, shaderCompute.program(), "feed", 0.007f);
        setShaderUniformFloat(gl, shaderCompute.program(), "kill", 0.08f);
        setShaderUniformFloat(gl, shaderCompute.program(), "Tech", 1f);

        setShaderUniformFloat(gl, shaderCompute.program(), "currentFrame", currentFrame);
        setShaderUniformFloat2(gl, shaderCompute.program(), "resolution", CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

        drawDataBuffer(shaderCompute, true);

        shaderCompute.useProgram(gl, false);
        fbo[currentDestBuffer].unbind(gl);
    }

   void drawDataBuffer(ShaderProgram currentShader, boolean sencondImage) {
       // --- draw vbo
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        //textcoords
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboTextCoord);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0); 
       //vertices
        gl.glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertices );
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        //activate texture data from last fbo
        final FBObject.Colorbuffer texSource = (FBObject.Colorbuffer) fbo[currentSourceBuffer].getColorbuffer(0);
        gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texSource.getName());
        setShaderUniform1i(gl, currentShader.program(), "textureData", 0);

        if (sencondImage) {
            //activate texture with image from file
            gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureFile.getTextureObject());
            textureFile.bind(gl);
            setShaderUniform1i(gl, currentShader.program(), "textureImage", 1);
        }

        //draw buffer on screens
       gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, canvasVertices.length / 3);

       //disable texture image
       if (sencondImage) {
           gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
           textureFile.disable(gl);
       }
       //disable texture data
       gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
       gl.glDisable(texSource.getName());

       gl.glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
       gl.glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

   }

  public void renderFBOToScreen()
    {
         gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear color and depth buffers
         gl.glLoadIdentity();  // reset the model-view matrix

         viewOrtho(gl);
        gl.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 

        final FBObject.Colorbuffer tex0 = (FBObject.Colorbuffer) fbo[currentDestBuffer].getColorbuffer(0);
        gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex0.getName());

        //activate shader
        shaderVisu.useProgram(gl, true);

        // --- draw vbo
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        //textcoords
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTextCoord);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0); 
       //vertices
        gl.glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertices );
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        //draw buffer on screens
       gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, canvasVertices.length / 3);

       gl.glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
       gl.glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
        //desactivate shader
        shaderVisu.useProgram(gl, false);

    }

   private void initFBO()
   {
       try {

       gl.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

       fbo = new FBObject[2];

       //first fbo
       fbo[currentSourceBuffer] = new FBObject(); // Create FrameBuffer
       fbo[currentSourceBuffer].init(gl, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 0);
       fbo[currentSourceBuffer].reset(gl, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 0); // int width, height - size of FBO, can be resized with the same call
       fbo[currentSourceBuffer].bind(gl);

       int tex = genTexture(gl);
       gl.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
       gl.glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, null);
       fbo[currentSourceBuffer].attachTexture2D(gl, 0, GL_RGBA32F, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, GL_NEAREST, GL_NEAREST, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       //gl.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
       int DrawBuffers[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
       gl.glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers, 0); // "1" is the size of DrawBuffers
       fbo[currentSourceBuffer].unbind(gl);

       //second fbo
       fbo[currentDestBuffer] = new FBObject(); // Create FrameBuffer
       fbo[currentDestBuffer].init(gl, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 0);
       fbo[currentDestBuffer].reset(gl, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 0); // int width, height - size of FBO, can be resized with the same call
       fbo[currentDestBuffer].bind(gl);

       tex = genTexture(gl);
       gl.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
       gl.glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, null);
       fbo[currentDestBuffer].attachTexture2D(gl, 0, GL_RGBA32F, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, GL_NEAREST, GL_NEAREST, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       //ogl.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
       gl.glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers, 1); // "1" is the size of DrawBuffers
       fbo[currentDestBuffer].unbind(gl);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Problem with fbo init " + e);
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   private Texture initializeTexture() { 

       Texture t = null; 

       try { 
           t = TextureIO.newTexture(new File("e:/shaders/wiki.jpg"), false); 

           t.setTexParameteri(gl, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
           t.setTexParameteri(gl, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
           t.setTexParameteri(gl, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
           t.setTexParameteri(gl, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 

       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Unable to read texture file: " + e);
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return t; 
   } 

   private ShaderProgram loadShader(GL2 gl, String vertexShader, String fragmentShader)
   {
           ShaderCode vertShader = ShaderCode.create(gl, GL2.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, 1, getClass(), new String[]{"e:/shaders/"+vertexShader},false);
           vertShader.compile(gl);

           ShaderCode fragShader = ShaderCode.create(gl, GL2.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, getClass(), new String[]{"e:/shaders/"+fragmentShader},false);
           fragShader.compile(gl);

           ShaderProgram newShader = new ShaderProgram();
           newShader.init(gl);
           newShader.add(vertShader);
           newShader.add(fragShader);

           newShader.link(gl, System.out);

           vertShader.destroy(gl);
           fragShader.destroy(gl);

           return newShader;
   }

   public static void setShaderUniform1i(GL2 inGL,int inProgramID,String inName,int inValue) {
       int tUniformLocation = inGL.glGetUniformLocation(inProgramID,inName);
       if (tUniformLocation != -1) {
           inGL.glUniform1i(tUniformLocation, inValue);
       } else {
           System.out.println("UNIFORM COULD NOT BE FOUND! NAME="+inName);
       }
   }

   public static void setShaderUniformFloat(GL2 inGL,int inProgramID,String inName,float inValue) {
       int tUniformLocation = inGL.glGetUniformLocation(inProgramID,inName);
       if (tUniformLocation != -1) {
           inGL.glUniform1f(tUniformLocation, inValue);
       } else {
           System.out.println("UNIFORM COULD NOT BE FOUND! NAME="+inName);
       }
   }
   public static void setShaderUniformFloat2(GL2 inGL,int inProgramID,String inName,float inValue1 ,float inValue2) {
       int tUniformLocation = inGL.glGetUniformLocation(inProgramID,inName);
       if (tUniformLocation != -1) {
           inGL.glUniform2f(tUniformLocation, inValue1, inValue2);
       } else {
           System.out.println("UNIFORM COULD NOT BE FOUND! NAME="+inName);
       }
   }

   private void viewOrtho(GL2 gl)  // Set Up An Ortho View
   {
       gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  // Select Projection
       gl.glPushMatrix();      // Push The Matrix
       gl.glLoadIdentity();      // Reset The Matrix
       gl.glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0); 
       gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  // Select Modelview Matrix
       gl.glPushMatrix();      // Push The Matrix
       gl.glLoadIdentity();     // Reset The Matrix
   }

   private int genTexture(GL2 gl) {
        final int[] tmp = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, tmp, 0);
        return tmp[0];
    }

   /**
    * Called back before the OpenGL context is destroyed. Release resource such as buffers.
    */
   @Override
   public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { }
}
```

And the corresponding GLSL Shader :

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D textureData;
uniform sampler2D textureImage;


uniform vec2 resolution;

uniform float diffuseU;
uniform float diffuseV;
uniform float feed;
uniform float kill;
uniform float Tech = 1.0;
uniform float currentFrame = 0.0;

void main() {
    //coords
    vec2 position = ( gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy );
    vec2 pixel = 1./resolution;

    //get data from texture
    vec4 imgSource = texture2D(textureImage, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec2 oldUV = texture2D(textureData, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rg;

    if(currentFrame<10){
        if (distance(position,vec2(0.5,0.5 - currentFrame * 0.01f)) < 0.2f)
            oldUV =  vec2(0.0,0.2);
        else if (distance(position,vec2(0.5,0.5 - currentFrame * 0.01f)) < 0.3f)
            oldUV =  vec2(0.5,0.1);
        else
            oldUV =  vec2(0.1,0.0);

        gl_FragColor =  vec4(oldUV.rg, 0.0, 1.0);
        return;
    }

    //get neightboors
    vec2 dataUp = texture2D(textureData, position + pixel * vec2(0., 1.)).rg;
    vec2 dataDown = texture2D(textureData, position + pixel * vec2(0., -1.)).rg;
    vec2 dataLeft = texture2D(textureData, position + pixel * vec2(-1., 0.)).rg;
    vec2 dataRight = texture2D(textureData, position + pixel * vec2(1., 0.)).rg;
    //adapt parameters
    vec2 imgParam = imgSource.rg;
    float dU = diffuseU ;//+ 0.01 * (imgParam - 0.5);
    float dV = diffuseV ;//+ 0.01 * (imgParam - 0.5);
    float F = feed ;//+ 0.01 * (imgParam - 0.5);
    float K = kill ;//+ 0.01 * (imgParam - 0.5);
    //compute new values
    vec2 laplace = (dataUp+dataDown+dataLeft+dataRight) - 4.0 * oldUV;
    float uvv = oldUV.r * oldUV.g * oldUV.g;
    // calculate delta quantities
    float du = dU * laplace.r - uvv + F*(1.0 - oldUV.r);
    float dv = dV * laplace.g + uvv - (F+K)*oldUV.g;
    vec2 newUV = oldUV + vec2(du, dv)* Tech;

    gl_FragColor =  vec4(newUV.rg, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few considerations:

- avoid deprecated OpenGL (and GLU), use GL4 (or GL3)
- unless you need awt/swt/swing, prefer newt, more [here](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/NEWT-Overview.html)
- prefer `Animator` instead of `FPSAnimator`, more [here](http://forum.jogamp.org/FPSAnimator-Vs-Animator-td4025734.html)
- prefer direct buffers instead of arrays, since otherwise jogl has to create them underneath and you can't keep trace (= deallocate when done) of those native allocations
- GL4 will allow you also to avoid all those uniform overhead (and also potential bugs) you have to deal with (especially during runtime), thanks to explicit locations
- prefer direct buffer management instead of FBObject for the moment unless you really know what FBObject is doing. Once you get it working, you can move on using that class. This may be (one of the) cause your code is not working, because something is not getting setup up as you need. Moreover, the lines of codes needed to replace FBObject are essentially the same
- (if you can't use explicit location for any reason) prefer some literal way to define the texture uniform location, it is usually another tricky part causing bugs, something like [this](https://github.com/elect86/helloTriangle/blob/master/HelloTriangle/src/framework/Semantic.java#L60-L66)
- prefer also a sampler for the textures, gives you more flexibility
- don't wait one week next time, let us know earlier! :) Frustation can be a nasty thing that put you down easily. Together we can help you getting it working ;)

Comment: Wow ! many thanks for all these considerations. Specially the last one ;) I will follow that to trying make it works